# imageWithContentsOfFile causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, image

Both of the below statements work. But the 2nd statement gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageNamed:photoFilenameNoPath], self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filenameWithPath], self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

I traced it down to `[image autorelease]` in:

```
    - (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {

        NSString *alertTitle;
        NSString *alertMessage;

        if (error == nil) {
            // Display UIAlertView to tell user that photo have been saved
            alertTitle = @"Photo Saved";
            alertMessage = @"";
        }
        else {
            // Display UIAlertView with error string to tell user that photo have NOT been saved
            alertTitle = @"Photo Not Saved";
            alertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ERROR SAVING:%@",[error localizedDescription]];
        }

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle message:alertMessage delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];                                                                                                              
        [alert show];
        [alert release];        

        [image autorelease];
    }
```

I need to use `imageWithContentsOfFile` because some of my files are in the Documents folder, and some are in the main bundle.

Anyone can help explain why I don't need to release `image` if I use `imageWithContentsOfFile` instead of `imageNamed`?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to place [image autorelease] in your code. In the Cocoa framework, you only call release or autorelease when you have typed 'alloc' or 'retain', otherwise leave the object alone. Both UIImage methods you are using did not call alloc or retain, thus you don't need to (auto)release them yourself.

Convinience class methods that return a new object are always autoreleased, that is released at a later point, if you want to keep them from being released, call retain. After that you must call 'release' or 'autorelease' to free the object.

If you don't free the object it will stay in the memory taking up space. For iOS I recommend that you use avoid using autorelease as much as possible since objective c has no swap space and limited memory.

Answer (score 0):

The second statement only works because you are lucky (and because there is an extra retain at this point on `image`, caused by something else than your code).

None of the two function `imageNamed:` and `imageWithContentsOfFile:` imply by their name that you have ownership of the returned `image` object. This means that you don't have to do a release on it.

> You own any object you create.
>   You create an object using a method whose name begins with “**alloc**”, “**new**”, “**copy**”, or “**mutableCopy**” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).

Following this rule, neither `imageWithContentsOfFile:` nor `imageNamed:` give you ownership of the created object. You don't own it, you don't (auto)-release it.

To read more on this, go to [Apple Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1).

---

I'm surprised CLANG didn't catch this error. Verify in your project settings that *Run Static Analyser* is turned on. It will help you a lot while trying to apprehend the Cocoa memory management concept.